# Branch.io crash when launching Android app AFTER hitting home button and relaunching app using deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I have deep linking working with Branch.io but I’m getting a strange crash in my Android implementation.

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Install app and run it normally.
2. Exit app and remove it from memory (DON’T uninstall, just make sure it’s out of memory)
3. Launch the app using a deep link
4. The app functions as expected
5. Hit the home button which puts the app in the background and goes to the launcher screen
6. Hit the app icon which brings the app back into focus
7. CRASH

This only seems to happen if the app is ALREADY installed and launched using a deep link.  If the app isn’t installed and must be installed as part of clicking on the deep link, this behavior doesn’t occur.

On top of the already weird behavior, I can’t figure out where it’s crashing.  Here is the crash log:

```
 03-10 16:13:21.215 13901-13901/com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app/com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app.activities_fragments.CXMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0088 (com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app:id/fragment_container) for fragment CXStartupFragment{42193e78      #0 id=0x7f0b0088}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3337)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0088 (com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app:id/fragment_container) for fragment CXStartupFragment{42193e78 #0 id=0x7f0b0088}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:2915)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentController.java:249)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:816)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:795)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:388)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
    at com.xxxx.videocollaboration.app.activities_fragments.CXMainActivity.onDestroy(CXMainActivity.java:294)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5352)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3324)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxxxx.videocollaboration.app"
android:versionCode="163"
android:versionName="2.8.1 (163)" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:name=".main.CXApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Branch.io values -->
    <!-- <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" /> -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="@string/branch_key" />
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities_fragments.CXMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="@string/branch_uri_scheme" android:host="@string/branch_host" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <service
        android:name=".services.NetworkTestService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".services.CXFileUploadService"
        android:exported="false"/>


</application>
```

Here is the onStart menthod in my main activity:

```
     @Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    // Configure Branch.io
    initiatedBranchDeepLinks = true;
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
                String message = "Branch.io onInitFinished. Params: " + referringParams.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, message);

                String databaseGUID = referringParams.optString(LINK_PARAM_DATABASE_GUID);
                String conferenceCode = referringParams.optString(LINK_PARAM_CONFERENCE_CODE);
                if(!CXStringUtils.isNullOrBlank(databaseGUID)) {
                    CXAppConfig.getSharedInstance().setTargetDatabaseGUID(databaseGUID);
                }
                if(!CXStringUtils.isNullOrBlank(conferenceCode)) {
                    CXAppConfig.getSharedInstance().setConferenceCode(conferenceCode);
                }

                ApiService apiService = ApiService.getInstance();
                apiService.get(CXMainActivity.this, ApiCall.GET_ENVIRONMENT_INFO_GET, new HashMap<String, String>(), HashMap.class, initCallBack);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}
```

UPDATE: It's crashing on the initSession call when the app is relaunched.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the manifest and the relevant activities that have been defined in code.

Comment: See edits above.